# SQL query to get result for a date range when table got Year and Month fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, where-clause

I have a table with Year and Month fields. I need to select the rows between two particular dates. How do I set this in the where condition?
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Something like `...where yearcol * 100 + monthcol between 201601 and 201612`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I added a sample data set. I use SQL server.

Comment: are the years and dates stored as numbers (as opposed to strings?)

Answer (score 3):

You are a bit unclear on what "between" means in this context.  I'm pretty sure that `datefromparts()` can be quite helpful:

```
select t.*
from t
where @date_start <= datefromparts(year, month, 1) and
      @date_end >= datefromparts(year, month, 1);
```

You might also find [`eomonth()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) helpful, if the end of the month is an important date.

Comment: Nice :)  But I think its only available in SQL Server 2012 onwards

Comment: @Grantly . . . Well, yes, and that software has been out for over 5 years.

Comment: LOL Yes indeed, I am so behind these days.  Just mentioned it in case anyone had trouble using that function, like me.  I have many versions running, but still not up to 2012,2014 yet (Although some of my clients are)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with help month(),year() function of date

Here is the example:

> select * from t where (t.month=month('2017-01-01') and t.year=year('2017-01-01')) and (t.month=month('2017-05-01') and t.year=year('2017-05-01'));

Below is the link for month() in sql.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql

This might help you in solving your problem.

Comment: Pretty sure the problem requires a result between two dates, not equal to two dates - which looks like it wouldn't work anyway...But nice attempt.  Perhaps you can improve your answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can also try something like:

```
select
  d.*
from
  (select
    t.*,
    cast(rtrim(cast([month] as char(2))) + '/1/' + cast ([year] as char(4)) as date) as dt) d
where
dt >= @dateStart and
dt <= @dateEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

If the year and month values are integers, you can cast them to varchar, then date, and use BETWEEN.  An example with declaring startdate and enddate variables:

```
DECLARE @startdate date = '2015-07-01'
       ,@enddate   date = '2016-07-01'

SELECT *       
  FROM @myTable
WHERE CAST(CAST(Year as varchar) + '-' + CAST(Month as varchar) + '-01' as date) 
      BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

If they are chars or varchars you need only cast to date and use BETWEEN:

```
DECLARE @startdate date = '2015-07-01'
       ,@enddate   date = '2016-07-01'

SELECT *       
  FROM @myTable
WHERE CAST(Year + '-' + Month + '-01' as date) 
      BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with "Between".

Something like this:

SELECT SALES_AMOUNT FROM TABLE WHERE YEAR BETWEEN 2015 AND 2016 AND MONTH BETWEEN 6 AND 8